# Powershell: how to remove multiple & directories with exceptions?

Tags: windows, powershell, recursion, filesystems, powershell-2.0

### The Setup

I have a folder structure that looks like:

```
C:\RootFolder
            \file1.txt
            \file2.txt
            \license.txt
            \Settings
                     \fileA.txt
                     \fileB.txt
                     \settings.txt
            \OtherFolders
```

### The Goal

Delete all of the files except for license.txt and settings.txt.

I would like in the end for only the following to remain:

```
  C:\RootFolder
                \license.txt
                \Settings
                         \settings.txt
```

### The Script to Far

```
$exclude = @('license.txt', 'settings.txt')
Get-ChildItem C:\RootFolder -recurse -exclude $exclude | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname -recurse:$false}
```

### The Problem

Even though I specify -recurse:$false specifically, it always generates a message for each folder indicating that "recurse isn't specified" and saying it will delete all child items.

After this, the license.txt file remains, but the settings.txt file (in a subdirectory) does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And almost as soon as I posted, the answer came to me -- I had to find only files, not directories.

Since I'm on PowerShell 2.0, I couldn't use the -File attribute that's new in powershell 3. Instead, I have to check every object to see if it's a container.

### Solution:

```
$exclude = @('license.txt', 'settings.txt')

Get-ChildItem C:\RootFolder -recurse -exclude $exclude | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

This worked perfectly to achieve what I needed.

### Improving on the Solution

Thanks to several comments / posts here, there are some more elegant ways that taught me a bit more about powershell:

- Remove-Item can take commands from a pipe-line. No foreach is necessary.
- Where-Object can just be shortened to "?"
- Get-ChildItem can be shortened to "gci" (alias)
- We don't need a ($_) after the Foreach. Foreach understands that automatically.
- If we wanted to put the excludes on one line, we can do it via an array right inline

Given these, an elegant solution that fits into a one-liner would be:

```
gci C:\RootFolder -Recurse -Exclude @('license.txt', 'settings.txt') | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: `Remove-Item` can read from a pipe, so you can simplify that statement to `gci C:\RootFolder -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Force`.

Answer (score 1):

You code works great.

Just a one-liner so we can do it another way:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\RootFolder -recurse | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | Foreach { if ( $_.Name -ne "license.txt" -and $_.Name -ne "settings.txt") {remove-item $_.FullName -force}}
```

If there are a lot of files need to be excluded then this one liner doesn't scale - in that case I will use your code:)

@Sean Killeen by the way:　Ｉｓ　ｔｈｅｒｅ　ａ　（＄＿）　ａｆｔｅｒ　ｆｏｒｅａｃｈ？ Sounds like you are using Foreach-Object Cmdlet instead of Foreach construct. My understanding is for Cmdlet we don't need ($something in $sometingElse） after "foreach-object". But in Foreach construct we need ($something in $somethingElse). Correct me if I am wrong.